# Drive API: DeadlineExceededException when updating a file

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm receiving DeadlineExceededException on Google App Engine when updating file via the Drive API (PUT method).

I'm playing with the sample Python application (https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python) so it uses resumable upload.
I trying to move this update in a task, which is working great.

I'm now wondering how to send the response back to the client after the task is completed or failed (since save is a sensible case, I want the user to be alerted if something goes wrong).

I've heard about the Channel API in GAE which seems to fit my need: http://prezi.com/uu_yezcaiqxc/channel-api-on-google-app-engine/

Thanks your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a datastore collections for the upload jobs and the background task could update the job's row when it's successfully completed or halted with an error.

```
id   | userId       | fileId     | status
-----+--------------+------------+-----------------
...  | user1        | file1      | 2 /* completed successfully */
...  | user1        | file2      | -1 /* error */
...  | user2        | file3      | 0 /* waiting to be uploaded */
```

You can query the collection to output the current status. You don't need to primarily use the Channel API to implement this flow but Channel API is also one of the options.

Comment: Yes I thought about it but it means that my client-side needs to poll until task is done, right?

Comment: Yes, you can poll. Or only show the latest status on page refresh. Depends on how fast you'd like to notify the user :)

Comment: Since it is saving, I would like to notify ASAP! Very sensible. I would prefer push actually.

Comment: Then, Channel API is a more fitting solution.

Comment: Perfect, I managed to make it works properly with the Channel API